# Firebase/ Flutter: Get Current User inside get function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get the current user from Firebase

```
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
```

inside get function like so:

```
class DatabaseService{
    Stream<List<AdModel>> get myAds {
    
        final CollectionReference userAdCollection = Firestore.instance.collection(uid);
        print(uid);
    
        return userAdCollection.snapshots()
            .map(_adListFromSnapshot);
    
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```dart
class DatabaseService{
    Future<FirebaseUser> get user => _auth.currentUser();
}
```

To finally get the user the following lines in an async function:

```dart
DatabaseService service = DatabaseService();
FirebaseUser user = await service.user;
```

Comment: the problem is I need user uid inside  Stream<List<AdModel>> get myAds { } to pass it for CollectionRefrence